# JQuery not working after AJAX Pagination

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a JQuery function/script that I'm using for posts on a blog that upon hover of the post image shows the post title, excerpt, and link.

Additionally, I have an AJAX Fade Out/Fade In pagination script running and when I go to the next set of posts in the pagination, the first JQuery script doesn't run any longer.  I know I need to be using the .live function somehow for jQuery, however I can't seem to figure it out.  Here are the two scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
            $(".capslide_img").capslide({
                caption_color : '#516077',
                caption_bgcolor : '#dbe2f0',
                overlay_bgcolor : '#dbe2f0',
                border   : '4px solid #dbe2f0',
                showcaption     : false
            });

        });
    </script>



 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 jQuery('#postPagination a').live('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
  jQuery('#page-wrap').fadeOut(500).load(link + ' #contentInner', function(){ jQuery('#page-wrap').fadeIn(500); });

 });

 });

 </script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are these two script blocks really separate, or can they be combined?

Answer (score 2):

you could put the `capslide` command into a function and call it after each ajax load:

```
function addCappslide() {
  $(".capslide_img").capslide({
    caption_color : '#516077',
    caption_bgcolor : '#dbe2f0',
    overlay_bgcolor : '#dbe2f0',
    border   : '4px solid #dbe2f0',
    showcaption     : false
  });
}

$(function() {
  addCappslide(); // call it once the page has loaded

  $('#postPagination a').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#page-wrap').fadeOut(500).load(link + ' #contentInner', function(){
      jQuery('#page-wrap').fadeIn(500, addCappslide() ); // call it after each ajax load again after it faded in
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I had tried that, however the fade functionality doesn't work when you do this.  Thoughts?

Comment: how about jQuery('#page-wrap').fadeIn(500, addCappslide()) ? or doesn't even the fadeOut part work in your case?

Comment: i edited the answer to call the function after fading in, is it working now? or does it look bad when the "caption" pops in after it faded in (does it?)

Comment: Neither of those seem to fix the issue.  It won't fade in or out with the function in there.  If I take it out it's fine, so it's got to be something with that function that's causing the fade in/out not to work.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I missed something in the above scripts.  IT WORKS!  Thanks so much markus!